# Combine R Splits

Tags: r, merge, split, combinations

Any way to combine splits?

I have two splits, `dfa` and `dfb`.

`dfa` is a Large list (4 elements) with 4 variables i.e. `dfa[[1]]` selects the first split

`dfb` is also a Large list (11 elements) with the same 4 variables.

Is there any way to make it as follows:

`dfc` Large List (15 elements)

I want `dfc[[1]]` to be the same as `dfa[[1]]` and `dfc[[5]]` to be the same as `dfb[[1]]`.

I have tried to bind these but `cbind`/`rbind` does not work.

Comment: Providing some data will help people help you.

Comment: are you simply looking for `dfc <- c(dfa,dfb)`?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try two things. If this doesn't solve your problem, do comment.

**Sample Data:**

```
dfa <- list(a = data.frame(a1 = c(1,2,3), b1 = c(2,3,4)),
            b = data.frame(a1 = c(4,5,6), b1 = c(5,6,7)))
```

**Method1:**

```
> library(dplyr)
> bind_rows(dfa)

  a1 b1
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  3  4
4  4  5
5  5  6
6  6  7
```

**Method 2:**

```
> library(purrr)
> map_df(dfa, rbind)

  a1 b1
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  3  4
4  4  5
5  5  6
6  6  7
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dfa <- list(a = c("a", "b"), b = c(1:3), c = c(1:5), d = c("hello"))
dfb <- list(a = c(1:5), b = c(3:6), c = c("hello", "world"), d = c(5:6), e = c(5:6), f = c("hi", "hi"), g = c("hello", "there"), h = c(1:5))
dfc <- c(dfa, dfb)
```

dfc[[1]] gives you dfa[[1]] and dfc[[5]] gives you dfb[[1]]